split strings of multiple columns into separate rows using only base R
I have tried to use the answer in this post using base R: Splitting a string into new rows in R
split_dfcheck <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, apply(test, 1, function(x) {
  do.call(expand.grid, strsplit(x, " *; *"))
})))

however, when I use it on my example data:
test <-data.frame(name=c("Andrea;barbara;erica;Matteo","Matteo;sonia;marta","Matteo;sonia","sonia;marta;matteo" ),  code=c("A", "A", "B", "B"),number=c(1,1,2,2),
                  surname=c("surname1;surname2;surname3;surname4", "surname1;surname2;surname3", "surname1;surname2","surname1;surname2;surname3"))

I get 38 rows while using separate_rows I get 12 rows:
test1 <- test %>%
  separate_rows(c(name,surname), , sep = ";")

Is there a way to get the same result as with separate_rows but using base R?
thanks!

test2 <- do.call(
  rbind,
  apply(test, 1, \(x) as.data.frame(sapply(x, strsplit, ";")))
)
test2
#       name code number  surname
# 1   Andrea    A      1 surname1
# 2  barbara    A      1 surname2
# 3    erica    A      1 surname3
# 4   Matteo    A      1 surname4
# 5   Matteo    A      1 surname1
# 6    sonia    A      1 surname2
# 7    marta    A      1 surname3
# 8   Matteo    B      2 surname1
# 9    sonia    B      2 surname2
# 10   sonia    B      2 surname1
# 11   marta    B      2 surname2
# 12  matteo    B      2 surname3

Has the drawback of converting all columns to character though. If you only have character/numeric you could fix that with
numeric_columns <- Filter(\(x) is.numeric(test[[x]]), names(test))
test2[numeric_columns] <- lapply(test2[numeric_columns], as.numeric)


thanks a lot! this really worked for me,
what would be the equivalent of
test3 <- test2 %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "code", values_from = "number")

using reshape in base R?
 name    surname  A     B    
   <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>
 1 Andrea  surname1 1     NA   
 2 barbara surname2 1     NA   
 3 erica   surname3 1     NA   
 4 Matteo  surname4 1     NA   
 5 Matteo  surname1 1     2    
 6 sonia   surname2 1     2    
 7 marta   surname3 1     NA   
 8 sonia   surname1 NA    2    
 9 marta   surname2 NA    2    
10 matteo  surname3 NA    2 
``

@i.b I would look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Yes, in the end I used reshape to get this output! thanks!

Using only base R, you could create a unique data frame from each row of the original using strsplit inside lapply and rbind the resultant list together into a single data frame that is identical to the output from separate_rows
test2 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(seq(nrow(test)), function(i) {
  data.frame(name = strsplit(test$name[i], ';')[[1]], 
             code = test$code[i], number = test$number[i],
             surname = strsplit(test$surname[i], ';')[[1]])
}))

This results in
test2
#>       name code number  surname
#> 1   Andrea    A      1 surname1
#> 2  barbara    A      1 surname2
#> 3    erica    A      1 surname3
#> 4   Matteo    A      1 surname4
#> 5   Matteo    A      1 surname1
#> 6    sonia    A      1 surname2
#> 7    marta    A      1 surname3
#> 8   Matteo    B      2 surname1
#> 9    sonia    B      2 surname2
#> 10   sonia    B      2 surname1
#> 11   marta    B      2 surname2
#> 12  matteo    B      2 surname3

Which we can see is identical to the output from separate_rows (except that separate_rows produces a non-base R tibble)
test1 <- test %>%
  separate_rows(c(name,surname), , sep = ";")

identical(as.data.frame(test1), test2)
#> [1] TRUE


Unfortunately those answers you link to, and the ones linked from that question, all are designed to work with only one column to split and/or only one column that is not split.
Here is a more general solution working with any number of columns to split or not split---though it will only work if the number of splits are the same in all split columns.
cols_to_split = c("name", "surname")
splits = lapply(test[cols_to_split], strsplit, split = ";")
## make sure the number of splits is the same in all split columns
if((splits |> lengths() |> unique() |> length()) != 1) stop("mismatched splits")

result = cbind(
  ## repeat the non-split columns the right number of times
  test[
    rep(1:nrow(test), times = lengths(splits[[1]])),
    setdiff(names(test), cols_to_split),
    drop = FALSE
  ],
  ## and add the split columns
  lapply(splits, unlist)
)

result
#     code number    name  surname
# 1      A      1  Andrea surname1
# 1.1    A      1 barbara surname2
# 1.2    A      1   erica surname3
# 1.3    A      1  Matteo surname4
# 2      A      1  Matteo surname1
# 2.1    A      1   sonia surname2
# 2.2    A      1   marta surname3
# 3      B      2  Matteo surname1
# 3.1    B      2   sonia surname2
# 4      B      2   sonia surname1
# 4.1    B      2   marta surname2
# 4.2    B      2  matteo surname3


You could automate this:
my_separate_row <- function(x, cols, sep){
  cols <- as.character(substitute(cols))
  if(length(cols) > 1)cols <- cols[-1] 
  nms <- names(x)
  fn <- \(x)unlist(read.table(text = x, sep = sep, fill = TRUE,na.strings = ''))
  y <- na.omit(sapply(test[cols], fn))
  if(is.list(y)) stop('unequal lengths')
  id <- substr(rownames(y), 3, 3)
  cbind(x[id[ord <- order(id)], !nms%in%cols], y[ord,], row.names = NULL)[nms]
}

test |>
   my_separate_row(c(name, surname), sep = ';')

      name code number  surname
1   Andrea    A      1 surname1
2  barbara    A      1 surname2
3    erica    A      1 surname3
4   Matteo    A      1 surname4
5   Matteo    A      1 surname1
6    sonia    A      1 surname2
7    marta    A      1 surname3
8   Matteo    B      2 surname1
9    sonia    B      2 surname2
10   sonia    B      2 surname1
11   marta    B      2 surname2
12  matteo    B      2 surname3

